# Can I plot a point at an equal distance from a line in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So far in my code I have:

```
enter code here import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DATA
L = 0.1 #m, length of arm of cross
t = L/2 #m, thickness

# VECTORS OF COORDINATES OF THE CROSS
X = np.array([L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2, t/2, L, L])
Y = np.array([t/2, t/2, L, L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2])

# PLOT
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X,Y,color='C1')
ax.axis('equal')
fig.savefig("figure.pdf")
fig.show()
```

This gives me a plus sign shape. I am looking towards plotting four points inside the shape at an equal distance from the perimeter on all four ends(one on each end).

Comment: you could scale the first cross and put it inside or outside of the original cross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a scatter plot and defining the x and y values of the points  you want to plot.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DATA
L = 0.1 #m, length of arm of cross
t = L/2 #m, thickness

# VECTORS OF COORDINATES OF THE CROSS
X = np.array([L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2, t/2, L, L])
Y = np.array([t/2, t/2, L, L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2])

# PLOT
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.plot(X,Y,color='C1', linewidth=2.5)
ax.axis('equal')

point_x = [L - t/2, -L + t/2, 0, 0]
point_y = [0, 0, L-t/2, -L + t/2]

points = ax.scatter(point_x, point_y)
axis_off = ax.axis('off')
```

Comment: thank you! Helped a lot! Any chance you know how I can change the color and size of the points and make them look like this: ○    thanks again!

Comment: points = ax.scatter(point_x, point_y, marker='o', size=10**2)

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html